# Amavis release uses UNIX socket instead of inet tcp socket

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, amavis

I try to release an email out of the quarantine with Amavis-new using:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/amavisd-release MAIL_ID SECRET_ID
```

where MAIL_ID and SECRET_ID are ids found in the database table 'quarantine'.

I get the following error in bash:

```
Can't connect to UNIX socket /var/lib/amavis/amavisd.sock: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/amavisd-release line 271.
```

The contents of `/etc/amavis/conf.d/25-amavis_helpers` is:

```
$unix_socketname = undef; #disable to unix socket

$interface_policy{'SOCK'} = 'AM.PDP-SOCK';
$policy_bank{'AM.PDP-SOCK'} = {
  protocol => 'AM.PDP',
  auth_required_release => 0, # don't require secret-id for release
};


# apply policy bank AM.PDP-INET to some inet tcp socket, e.g. tcp port 9998:
$inet_socket_port = [10024,9998];
$interface_policy{'9998'} = 'AM.PDP-INET';

$policy_bank{'AM.PDP-INET'} = {
  protocol => 'AM.PDP',  # select Amavis policy delegation protocol
  inet_acl => [qw( 127.0.0.1 [::1] )],  # restrict access to these IP addresses
  auth_required_release => 0,  # don't require secret_id for amavisd-release
};
```

Amavis-new automatically uses the UNIX socket. The UNIX socket is disabled in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/25-amavis_helpers`. Is it possible to use the inet tcp socket in `/usr/sbin/amavisd-release`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I copied the script `/usr/sbin/amavisd-release` to another folder and changed the following lines from

```
### USER CONFIGURABLE:

  $log_level = 1;
# $socketname = '127.0.0.1:9998';
# $socketname = '[::1]:9998';
  $socketname = '/var/lib/amavis/amavisd.sock';

### END OF USER CONFIGURABLE
```

to

```
### USER CONFIGURABLE:

  $log_level = 1;
  $socketname = '127.0.0.1:9998';
# $socketname = '[::1]:9998';
# $socketname = '/var/lib/amavis/amavisd.sock';

### END OF USER CONFIGURABLE
```